# how to identify that a worksheet is minimized?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2007, excel-2010, vba

How to identify the current active worksheet is minimized ?
I do not want to run my operation when the current worksheet in excel is minimized. I am using excel interop and C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a conditional check on the following property,

```
If Application.WindowState = xlMinimized Then
        // do something
End If
```

This is in VBA though.

Here is a basic code in C#

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; 

Excel.Application myXL = new Excel.Application();
myXL.Visible = true;

//adding a new book
Excel.Workbook xlBookN = myXL.Workbooks.Add();

//opening exising book
String xlPath = "c:/myprojects/test.xls";
Excel.Workbook xlBookE = myXL.Workbooks.Open(xlPath,
    0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "",
    true, false, 0, true, false, false);

Dim myWindowState As XlWindowState //you could also use a variable
myXL.WindowState = myWindowState

//or you can check the state directly 
If (myXL.WindowState = xlMinimized)
        // do something
End If
```

*Please check on the syntax and references.*

You could get better reference from :

- [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa168292%28v=office.11%29.aspx#excelobj_link3)
- [MSDN OFFICE INTEROP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.windowstate%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

Comment: I want to check if the Worksheet is minimized or not, how can I do that ?

Comment: Sheet belongs to a book, book belongs to the application. So how many books are you planning to open *simultaneously* :$ ?

Comment: Would like to hear if you had your issue solved with above answer or along the same lines. :)

Comment: yes , actually i was confused because we can not minimize the sheets actually we can minimize the workbooks